# Is there a way to retrieve the Step Function tasktoken from within a Batch job?

Tags: boto3, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

I'm using the AWS Batch integration to AWS Step Functions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connectors-batch.html

The Batch job definition takes the parameters passed in from the Step Function and calls a python script on the container with those parameters.

Is there a way within this python script running on the container to pull the Step Function *taskToken* so that I can update the status and send back task success JSON to the calling Step Function (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskSuccess.html) to be used later in the flow?

Currently there doesn't seem to be any other way to get results from a Batch job back into StepFunctions.

Thanks!

Comment: I have been looking for a similar functionality with AWS Batch and AWS Step Functions but don't find any way to do this. Conclusion so far: (1) No way to control AWS Batch output in AWS Batch or AWS Step Functions, (2) no way to pass one information between two AWS Batch job, (3) no way to share a unique id between two AWS Batch job running in AWS Step Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a way to do this by passing the Task Token as an Environment Variable to the Container and picking it from process.env.

```
"ContainerOverrides":
  {
    "Environment":
      [
        { "Name": "TASK_TOKEN", "Value.$": "$$.Task.Token" },
      ]
  }
```

Your environment variable `TASK_TOKEN` will have the correct value inside the container.